# How to saveAll() when given a List<Long> into a M:M relationship in JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, entity

I'm really new to JPA stuff so I'm in a bit of a trouble here.

So I'm going through a project, and right now I'm working with 3 tables:
Influencer, Influencer_Campaign_Mapping, and Campaign.
Since Influencer: Campaign in my business is Many to Many,
I decomposed it into 1:M - M:1 relationship making the mapping table.

My entities look like this,

```
//Mapping Entity

@Entity 
@Getter 
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED) 
@Table(name = "CAMPAIGN_INFLUENCER_MAPPING") 
public class InfluencerCampaign {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CAMPAIGN_INFLUENCER_MAPPING_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAMPAIGN_ID")
    private Campaign campaign;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INFLUENCER_ID")
    private Influencer influencer;
```

```
//Campaign Entity

@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "CAMPAIGN")
public class Campaign implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CAMPAIGN_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long campaignId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<InfluencerCampaign> influencers = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
//Influencer Entity 

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "INFLUENCER")
public class Influencer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "INFLUENCER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "influencer")
    private List<InfluencerCampaign> influencerCampaigns;
```

So the problem rises in the very early stage.
So I want to take a List of influencers by the id. for example : '[1,2,3,4,5]' as @RequestBody,
and take in a single campaignId by @PathVariable.

The beginning of my controller looks like this,

```
    @PostMapping("/api/latest/campaign/{campaignId}/influencer")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addInfluencersToCampaign(@PathVariable("campaignId") Long campaignId,
                                                           @RequestBody List<Long> influencers){
        Campaign campaign = campaignService.findById(campaignId);
        campaignService.addInfluencersToCampaign(influencers.stream().map())
    }
```

but I can't seem to continue from here because I want to use .builder to make a List of entities to be able to use saveAll();

In my DTO,

I'm running into problems because campaign in the mapping table is saved as Campaign type.

```
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Request {
        private List<Long> influencers;
        private Campaign campaign;

        @Builder
        public Request(List<Long> influencers, Campaign campaign){
            this.influencers = influencers;
            this.campaign = campaign;
        }

        public List<InfluencerCampaign> toEntity(List<Long> influencers, Long campaignId) {
            return influencers.stream()
                    .map(influencerId -> new InfluencerCampaign(influencerId, campaignId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

All the examples I see are using @Setter which I really want to avoid.

I tried making different forms of DTOs,
but there wasn't much that I could try.
I tried making different constructors so that I can use different getters, but not much progress..

Comment: Well, I just had a huge enlightenment of how in a Entity based structure, entities are saved rather than the ID, so i will continue to figure out a way to do this, but i want some guidance :)